# Using the stale: "update_after" in PouchDB

Tags: pouchdb

According to the documentation options = {stale: 'update_after'} should return immediately and kick off an index update for the db.query().

Testing it with big databases (more than 5 000  docs and 40 MB) doesn't seem to work.  The index is not built in the background and the query waits for the index to be built before returning data.

Am I missing something there ?

Answer (score 2):

[It's a bug](https://github.com/pouchdb/mapreduce/pull/198). The fix should be available shortly, probably in PouchDB 3.0.0.  In the meantime, you can run a `query()` without any `stale` options in a separate callback to avoid blocking your own code.  Sorry about that, and thanks for letting us know!